Changing bounds in a gaussian integral
When integrating over the domain $[0,1]$, say, for example a Gaussian-type integral. Say we perform the subsitution $x = e^{-u}$ ($ u = - \ln x$). The new bounds of the integral will be the image of the interval when we apply the map u:
$$ u([0,1]) = [0, \infty) $$
So, the new bounds are from 0 to infinity. However, when we use software, we see that $u([0,1]) = (\infty, -0]$. Why is going on here? Any

Have you checked with the group or company providing the software?
